# Spring Security with JWT - Authenticated at every tenth call

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

I've some strange problem with my spring security configuration.
I use it with an simple JWT implementation.
I use "GlobalMethodSecurity" and annotated my method with @PreAuthorize

Here a secured sample method:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/ok", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity ok(  ) {
    return new ResponseEntity( "{text:\"ok\"}", HttpStatus.OK );
}
```

if I call this without a security token I get an "UNAUTHORIZED" nine times (as expected). At the exact tenth time I will get the "ok" json from the method. (The 11th to 19th call is "UNAUTHORIZED" and at the 20th I will became the "ok" message again and so on)

Here are my SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true )
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;


    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication( AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder ) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService( userDetailsService )
                .passwordEncoder( new BCryptPasswordEncoder() );
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean(name = "authenticationTokenFilter")
    public AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new AuthenticationTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager( super.authenticationManagerBean() );
        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity httpSecurity ) throws Exception {
        // Custom JWT based authentication
        httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore( authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class )
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint( authenticationEntryPoint )
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS )
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

    }
```

and my Filter Class:

```
public class AuthenticationTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenUtils tokenUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        tokenUtils = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext())
                .getBean(TokenUtils.class);
        userDetailsService = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext())
                .getBean(UserDetailsService.class);

        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, " + AppConstant.tokenHeader);


        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader(AppConstant.tokenHeader);
        String username = this.tokenUtils.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (this.tokenUtils.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

}
```

**Edit**
I found out that this only happen if a user was logged in once.
So in the example *ok()* method I had the previously logged in user in the security context although I haven't sent any token in the header.
But as I said - not in every request - There must be a kind of Thread or session thing I miss.

For a advice I would be very grateful
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter

Live Demo: http://fanjin.computer:8080

SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter() throws Exception {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public JwtLogoutHandler jwtLogoutHandler() {
        return new JwtLogoutHandler();
    }
    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS ).and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint( restAuthenticationEntryPoint ).and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/login.html", "/home.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated().and()
                .formLogin()
                    .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler).and()
                .logout()
                    .addLogoutHandler(jwtLogoutHandler())
                    .logoutSuccessHandler((new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))) ;
    }

}
```

Filter Class:

```
@Override
public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String authToken = getToken( request );
    // get username from token
    String username = tokenHelper.getUsernameFromToken( authToken );
    if ( username != null ) {
        // get user
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername( username );
        // create authentication
        TokenBasedAuthentication authentication = new TokenBasedAuthentication( userDetails );

        authentication.setToken( authToken );
        authentication.setAuthenticated( true );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you call loadUserByUsername, this will be called for each and every request.

Comment: We need that to obtain the userDetails and create an authentication object.